# Cannot push to heroku with cloudinary storing my staticfiles

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, cloudinary

I am trying to use cloudinary to store my media and static files for my django project. I am using `django-cloudinary-storage` package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/django-cloudinary-storage/). First I changed my settings so that media files are stored on cloudinary and pushed it to heroku and it worked fine except the staticfiles were not loading. So I changed my settings again so that static files are also stored in cloudinary. It works fine locally with `DEBUG=False`. When I see the page source of my html locally, it is getting the css and javascript files from cloudinary. So, then I tried pushing it to heroku using `git push heroku master`. But I get the below error in my heroku logs:

```
    Step 11/14 : RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    
     ---> Running in 5b062a8f7c52
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "/usr/src/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    
        main()
    
      File "/usr/src/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    
        utility.execute()
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 161, in handle
    
        if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 215, in is_local_storage
    
        return isinstance(self.storage, FileSystemStorage)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 248, in inner
    
        self._setup()
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 465, in _setup
    
        self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary_storage/storage.py", line 275, in __init__
    
        super(HashCloudinaryMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 400, in __init__
    
        self.hashed_files = self.load_manifest()
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 410, in load_manifest
    
        content = self.read_manifest()
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary_storage/storage.py", line 319, in read_manifest
    
        with self.manifest_storage.open(self.manifest_name) as manifest:
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 38, in open
    
        return self._open(name, mode)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary_storage/storage.py", line 47, in _open
    
        url = self._get_url(name)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary_storage/storage.py", line 78, in _get_url
    
        return cloudinary_resource.url
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary/__init__.py", line 305, in url
    
        return self.build_url(**self.url_options)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary/__init__.py", line 315, in build_url
    
        return self.__build_url(**options)[0]
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary/__init__.py", line 312, in __build_url
    
        return utils.cloudinary_url(public_id, **combined_options)
    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudinary/utils.py", line 736, in cloudinary_url
    
        raise ValueError("Must supply cloud_name in tag or in configuration")
    
    ValueError: Must supply cloud_name in tag or in configuration
    
    The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py collectstatic --noinput' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I already have `CLOUD_NAME`, `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET` as environment variables on heroku.
It also shows `The command '/bin/sh -c python manage.py collectstatic --noinput' returned a non-zero code: 1` which is in my `DockerFile`:

```
    FROM python:3.10
    
    
    # setting work directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    
    # env variables
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    ENV PYTHONDONTWEITEBYTECODE 1
    ENV DEBUG 0
    
    # install psycopg dependencies
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        libpq-dev \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
    
    # install dependencies
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    COPY requirements.txt .
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    
    
    COPY . .
    
    
    RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    
    
    RUN adduser -u 99 myuser
    USER myuser
    
    
    CMD gunicorn ramrobazar.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

And here's my `settings.py`:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'phonenumber_field',
        'ramrobazar.account.apps.AccountConfig',
        'ramrobazar.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
        'ramrobazar.inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',
        'ramrobazar.drf.apps.DrfConfig',
        'ramrobazar.demo.apps.DemoConfig',
        'mptt',
        'rest_framework',
        'rest_framework.authtoken',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
    
        'cloudinary_storage',
    
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
        'cloudinary',
        'corsheaders',
    ]
    
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        
        
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
        
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]
    
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.StaticHashedCloudinaryStorage'
    
    MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
    
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    
    CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
        'CLOUD_NAME': os.environ.get('CLOUD_NAME'),
        'API_KEY': os.environ.get('API_KEY'),
        'API_SECRET': os.environ.get('API_SECRET'),
    }
    
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
```

This is my first time using heroku and cloudinary. If anyone has any idea about what the problem might be, please share it. If any more information is required, please ask.

Comment: As the Heroku integration has some specific processes for integrating solutions like Cloudinary, I would recommend you to check the integration procedure as indicated  [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudinary) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary).

Comment: I am now using whitenoise again for staticfiles and cloudinary only for media files(images). It is working now.